# What is the right way of syncing a few folders across git branches?

Tags: git, branch

I have a Yii(PHP MVC) project with defined models, views and controllers. I have divided the application into different purposes by creating git branches and maintaining a single bare repository to manage all the branches such as api, dashboard, backend and others. Such a system help me split it on different autoscaling groups and servers.

Now, I have to make frequent changes to the models which need to be used in almost all the branches. The controllers and views are different in the different branches. What is the right way to setting this up. Is there a way to make a folder branch independent? The current system has same models with different functions which were created as required by the particular application. Often, I need a particular function in api server that I added in dashboard branch.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you correct. Is http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20111009/how-to-create-an-independent-branch-in-git/ what you're looking for?

Comment: Have you tried to work with yii modules and components? They have excellent features to handle separation or concerns and avoiding hard dependencies; you could work with your modules on each branch and use common components for your shared software elements. In fact your question give me an excellent idea!

Comment: @RishiDua That looks something similar to submodules. I think it needs to be configured during set up only. What I just need is a chronological merging of a folder.

Comment: @Alejandro The changes that I talk of are basically trying to make the models less dependent on the application, hence need the merging. The need is to merge the model folder containing active record classes.